# Is it necessary to use form tag in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have build a project without form *tag in angular 2.*
Is there some kind of lose if i won't use form tags in angular 2

Comment: Depends on what you want. Use forms for complex form control within the component. Or you can just add standard form control to inputs.